# How to replace Openreach RJ11 ADSL router with new RJ45 router?

Tags: wifi, router, upgrade, dsl

I live in the UK and my home has an openreach wall socket with a telephone line and an RJ11 ADSL line for my router similar to this:

[image: openreach wall socket]

However I want to upgrade my router as it's terribly slow and drops connection consistently on WiFi. The WiFi has terrible range etc and it's basically e-waste at this point.

I've found a few routers online but the ones I like all have RJ45 ports for the WAN connection.

Is there anyway I can use these since there's not a way currently I could connect them?

As I've tried looking around to see if I could get the openreach box changed so it has an RJ45 connection for WAN, but I can't seem to find any information on this?

Comment: Your ADSL modem connects to a regular phone line… that’s what defines it. You will need to contact OpenReach, Kelly’s, BT or whoever your contact is with, to upgrade the line.

Answer (score 0):

Off the shelf "routers" are really a modem, router, switch, and access point all rolled into one box. You can get a [DSL modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076N7CT5Q) and connect it to any new router+switch+access point combo like this [Archer AX21](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08H8ZLKKK) with an Ethernet cable.

Instead of buying a new modem, I recommend you disable all the features on your current box except the modem, and then plug it into a new router. It will not change the connection between the internet and your house, but it will make the connection to your local network faster and more stable.

If your current "router" doesn't give you the control to disable features, you can instead plug it's output(LAN) into the LAN (not WAN) port of the Archer linked above and, on the Archer, set it to access point mode. This will disable the DHCP and NAT on the archer essentially making your current box a modem+router and the new box a switch+access point.

Answer (score 0):

RJ11 connectors carry ADSL or VDSL.  RJ45 connectors (on the backs of routers) carry ethernet.  They aren't the same, so you can't simply adapt one to the other.

Your options are either a standalone modem box, that connects between the RJ11 phone socket and the ethernet port on a 'cable router' that you already have, or to buy a new router box that integrates the xDSL.

Practically speaking, there is no cost advantage in buying a separate modem over buying an integrated modem-router.  Doing the first just makes things more complicated and power hungry for minimal benefit.

You may be able to turn off enough features in your existing router to turn it into a pure modem, but that may not be possible, especially if it was originally supplied by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge WAN(wide access network) is mainly used to expand a network, for a wan modem, you would connect it up and it would be like a network booster with some ethernet ports on the back, to my knowledge, for a router you either get normal ADSL, NBN, or Fiber Optic.